# Combinations with multiple sets in c#

Tags: c#, performance, combinations, accord.net

I have three sets of points. I need all combinations having a maximum of one point per set.

[image]

From the picture above the result should be:

- p1, p3, p6
- p1, p3, p7
- p1, p4, p6
- p1, p4, p7
- p1, p5, p6
- p1, p5, p7
- p2, p3, p6
- p2, p3, p7
- p2, p4, p6
- p2, p4, p7
- p2, p5, p6
- p2, p5, p7
- p1, p3
- p1, p4
- p1,p5
- ...
- ...
- p4, p6
- ...
- p1
- p2
- ...

I'm using the method `Combinations` in

> Accord.Math

on all points from all the sets and after that I remove the combinations containing more points from the same set.
Instead of calculating the combinations I would like to calculate all the possible paths from Set1 to Set3 (passing also for Set2) because the Combinations take too much time for a large set of points.
How can I change my code?

```
  var result1 = new Dictionary<int, List<List<ClusterInPath>>>();      
  foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<ClusterInPath>> currentClustersInImage in allClustersInVertebra)
  {
    var allPaths = currentClustersInImage.Value.ToArray().Combinations().Select(el => el.ToList()).ToList();
    var filterPaths = new List<List<ClusterInPath>>();
    foreach (List<ClusterInPath> path in allPaths)
    {
      if(PathContainsMoreClustersOnSameImage(path)) continue;
       filterPaths.Add(path);
    }       
    result1.Add(currentClustersInVertebra.Key, filterPaths);
  }
```

The class ClusterInPath is defined below:

```
  public class ClusterInPath
  {
    public ClusterInPath(int imageIndex, int clusterIndex)
    {
      ImageIndex = imageIndex;
      ClusterIndex = clusterIndex;
    }

    public int ImageIndex { get; set; }
    public int ClusterIndex { get; set; }
   }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Add fictive (zero, empty etc) element into every set and get Cartesian product of sets. Ignore or remove these elements during output.

[Example of computing Cartesian product with LINQ](https://ericlippert.com/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/)